# How to insert custom properties to File object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, ecmascript-2016

I am working on file upload functionality , what I want to achieve when I select multiple files or single file I want to assign custom property to each `File` object custom property must be like `percentage:0` to File object. I tried hard but didn't find any proper solution to resolve this issue. Could someone please help me how to resolve this issue .

Thanks

**Code**

```
  addManualAttachments = (event) => {
    let files = event.target.files

    const fileList = Array.from(files)

    if (fileList.length > 10) {
      Swal.fire('Warning !', 'Maximum files upload limit is 10', 'warning')
      return false
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
      if (this.validateFile(fileList[i])) {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          return {
            ...prevState,
            selectedFiles: this.uniqueFiles([...prevState.selectedFiles, fileList[i]]),
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a plain Javascript object, you can add the new property right to the file as you loop over it. Also, you can use a forEach loop and don't need a for loop:

```
addManualAttachments = (event) => {
  const files = Array.from(event.target.files);

  if (files.length > 10) {
    Swal.fire('Warning !', 'Maximum files upload limit is 10', 'warning')
    return false
  }

  files.forEach((file) => {
    if(this.validateFile(file)) {
      file.percentage = 0; // <-- This will add the new property to the object reference stored for that file object.
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        return {
          ...prevState,
          selectedFiles: this.uniqueFiles([...prevState.selectedFiles, file]),
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```